# Qt : Is it possible to add a QVBoxLayout to a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

I currently populate my Tableview in the following manner

```
QStandardItem* item_one  =  new QStandardItem();
item_one->setText( "SomeText" ) ;

QStandardItem* item_two  =  new QStandardItem();
item_two->setText( "SomeTextTwo" ) ;

    QList<QStandardItem*> lst ;
    lst.push_back(item_one);
    lst.push_back(item_two);

standardItemModel->appendRow(lst);
```

I wanted to know if its possible to add a layout to a cell in a tableview using standardItemModel. The layout will be a vertical layout with two QLabels ?

Comment: What does the compiler says? Is he happy about it?

Comment: Fixed the last statement. The tableview does not show anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `setIndexWidget()` of view and apply there `QWidget` which has `QVBoxLayout` with your widget items there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just updated the post with your suggestion however its not being displayed

Comment: QVBoxLayout doesn't inherit from QWidget, I believe, so your cast there won't really work (in general, it's good to avoid explicit casts like that).  You might try creating a QFrame and setting the QVBoxLayout as the Frame Layout, then inserting the Frame.

Comment: I updated my code and this time I am attempting to add a QLabel but thats not being displayed as well